# Call a function at the end of multiple functions in rails observer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, observers

So, I'm using 'state_machine' gem in my app for making Lead model a state machine. And I wrote a lot of custom methods on transitions in the LeadObserver like below.

```
class LeadObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_review
  end

  def after_convert
  end

  def after_mark_invalid
  end
end
```

And there're around 15 methods like these.

Now, I have a class method, say `Seller.do_something` which has to be called at the end of all these 15 methods. Is there an elegant Rails way to call this `Seller.do_something` method at the end of every method like `after_filter` for controller. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

i think you can but its not great to use.

`ActiveModell::Callbacks` is what you are looking for.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Callbacks.html

state_machine itself does provide an `after_transition` - maybe thats helping you?